# Httpd Error Forbidden on Symlink

Tags: linux, apache, symlink

I tried to put all my laravel folders into my home directory and create a symlink. I am on fedora 23

my current laravel project  which is named blogger is under `/home/pitfu/web/blogger`

I created a symlink using this command

```
sudo ln -s /home/pitfu/web/blogger/public/ /var/www/html/blogger
```

in http.conf `Options Indexes FollowSymLink` is already there for `/var/www/html`

why do I get a Permission error?

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /blogger/ on this server.

when I do `ls -la` in `/var/www/html`

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 pitfu pitfu   61 Nov 20 13:48 blogger -> /home/pitfu/web/blogger/public/
```

Comment: hi if anyone would have this problem problem. i know this was a big mistake running chmod o+x on /home/pitfu but this was the one made it working. please try on the folder like /home/pitfu/web/blogger if it would work before on the home directory which is my mistake running the command directly

Comment: Instead of `chmod o+x` you can use `chmod g+rx` and set Group to your username in `/etc/httpd/httdp.conf`

Answer (score 0):

### Revised

After looking at this again I'm persuaded to believe that the `/var/www/html` folder may not have the adequate permissions set for the server.

Comment: this was the output when ls -la `drwxrwxrwx  4 pitfu pitfu     4096 Nov 20 14:01 public`

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be the permission for the symlink which is pointing the public subfolder, I don't think it's showing permissions for the blogger parent directory—that's what I'd like to see.

Comment: Also, is your server being started by another user/user-group? Does that have the adequate permissions?

Comment: permission on blogger folder is 777

Comment: Ok. What's the permission for `/var/www/html`?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x.  2 root      root         4096 Nov 20 14:40 html`